# Is it possible that $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y}$, yet $\mathcal{X} \in \mathcal{Y}$?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Is it possible for a set to equal another set, yet the former set be an element in the latter set?  I.e.:

$\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y}$, yet $\mathcal{X} \in \mathcal{Y}$

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: Also see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory).

Comment: It's much clearer to just ask, "Can a set be an element of itself?"

Comment: Working along the lines of @Noah, this is really just asking if $X\in X$ is even possible. I've marked this as a duplicate of a handful of questions related to this. There might be more.